# How do I fix redirecting for a react route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a question regarding redirecting in React.
here are my routes in my App.js file:

```
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login onLoginSuccess={setUserSession} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/register">
            <Register />
          </Route>
          <LoggedInRoute userData={getUserData()} path="/feed">
            <Feed />
          </LoggedInRoute>
        </Switch>
```

here is the LoggedInRoute component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function LoggedInRoute(props) {
  return (
    <Route
      render={({ location }) =>
        props.userData.id ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default LoggedInRoute;
```

here is the login fetch:

```
  const onFinish = values => {
    fetch('/api/login',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
      }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success === 1) {
        if (location.state.from) {
          history.push(location.state.from.pathname);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

my problem is that the redirect is not working after a successful login.
If I try to access '/feed' when I am not logged in, in the first place I am redirected to the '/login', but after a successful login I am not redirected back to the initial route (/feed).
I am not sure what I am missing. Thank you in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would go with this approach:

```
import { Redirect, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function LoggedInRoute({ userData, children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useEffect(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData || !userData.id) {
      setRedirect(true);
    }
  }, [userData]);

  if (redirect) {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: location }
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  return <Route component={<>{children}</>} />;
}
```

this way you won't get any `stale` data

Comment: this isn't working in my case. after the login is successful, history just don't want to work

Comment: If you tried my code I had a little typo in my code which I've fixed it. here in the line : ```return <Route component={<>{children}</>} />;``` try it again, I think It should work fine